# __get_free_page, physical address and swap

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, swap

Suppose to call `__get_free_page` in order to request the kernel a free page in `ZONE_NORMAL` zone, so with `GFP_KERNEL` flag. We know that the returned address is a kernel logical address so there exists a "permanent" mapping in the page table for that logical address and the physical address is calculated with the macro `__pa`. My question is: if exists a permanent mapping for that page, is the swapping to the disk possible for that page? If yes, i suppose that when it will be swapped in memory again, it will put every time in the same page frame...is this correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you allocate a page in the kernel with `__get_free_page` in the kernel, it is *not* swappable.  In Linux, a `struct page` tracks a physical page, which is not swappable.  Swapping works on the level of userspace mapping and their contents; so if userspace memory is swapped out, the contents may be swapped back into a different physical page.  But that physical page will be mapped at the same userspace virtual address.

Kernel memory is not swappable in Linux.

Comment: Thanks Roland. So, since a `mmap` anonymous region is tracked with a `struct page`, it is not swappable?

Comment: No, userspace mapped memory is swappable.  What happens is that the content of the page is written to swap, the PTE (page table entry) is marked as "not present", and the underlying `struct page` is returned to the free list for reuse.  The if userspace accesses the swapped out mapping, a new page is allocated and the old contents are read back in from swap.

Comment: Ok. I asked this because you wrote that `struct page` tracks a physical page that is not swappable and anonymous `mmap`ed regions (shared or not) are tracked with a `struct page`. You could correct your answer, it could be useful. Thank you!

Comment: I don't see where I said that mmap'ed regions are tracked with a struct page.  Almost all mmap regions (including anonoymous memory) are mappings of userspace virtual addresses to struct pages.  As I said, swapping occurs on page contents, not the pages themselves.

Comment: You didn't say that, books say this. What i mean is that if you say that every physical page tracked with a `struct page` is not swappable, and, for example, an anonymous `mmap`'ed page is tracked with a `struct page`, this means that a physical page `mmap`'ed in a process' address space, is not swappable. Am i wrong?

Comment: So, since userspace memory is swappable, maybe is not correct to say that `struct page` tracks only unswappable pages. Am i wrong?